# Cypress: How to save a variable and use it later for comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cypress

I have a `div` that has a value of `15,000` that can be retrieved by

```js
cy.get('.population').invoke('text').then((numbers) =>{
  let people = parseInt(numbers.replaceAll(',',''))
  cy.wrap(people).as('population')
})
```

However, I now need to get two other values in another div and then compare them to be sure they equal each other. This works, however, right after a successful assertion is throws this error

> `cy.then()` failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.
> In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.
> The value you synchronously returned was: `{__flags: Object{5}}`

Here is the entire code together.

```js
cy.elem('population').invoke('text').then((num) =>{
  let totalResidents = parseInt(num.replaceAll(',',''))
  cy.wrap(totalResidents).as('population')
})
cy.get('@population').then((population) => { 
  cy.get(`div[col-id=${columns.totalResidents}]`)
    .find('span').find('div')
    .then(($divs) => {
       const nums = [...$divs].map(div => div.innerText)
       const zcta1Pop = parseInt(nums[1].replaceAll(',',''))
       const zcta2Pop = parseInt(nums[2].replaceAll(',',''))
       const totalPop = zcta1Pop + zcta2Pop
       return cy.expect(population).to.eq(totalPop) //successful assertion 15000 = 15000 
                                                   // but then fails right after
})
```

The second pair of divs can be represented by

```html
 <span>
   <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
     <div>7,000</div>
   </div>
 </span>
 <span>
   <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
     <div>8,000</div>
   </div>
 </span>
```

The weird this is that the assertion at the end is correct `assert expected 15000 to equal 15000` but then throws the error. Does anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a custom command, `cy.expect()...` is wrong syntax. It should just be `expect()...` - but you cannot return it.

You don't need to return anything from your last `.then()` because you've already done the assertion.

An alias is unnecessary if you use the value immediately after.

```js
cy.elem('population').invoke('text')
  .then((num) =>{
    let totalResidents = parseInt(num.replaceAll(',',''))
    return cy.wrap(totalResidents)
  })
  .then(totalResidents1 => { 
    cy.get(`div[col-id="${columns.totalResidents}"]`)
      .find('span').find('div')
      .then(($divs) => {
        const nums = [...$divs].map(div => div.innerText)
        const zcta1Pop = parseInt(nums[1].replaceAll(',',''))
        const zcta2Pop = parseInt(nums[2].replaceAll(',',''))
        const totalResidents2 = zcta1Pop + zcta2Pop
        expect(totalResidents1).to.eq(totalResidents2)
      })
  })
```

Or with aliases

```js
cy.elem('population').invoke('text')
  .then(num => parseInt(num.replaceAll(',','')))
  .as('totalResidents1')

cy.get(`div[col-id="${columns.totalResidents}"]`)
  .find('span').find('div')
  .then($divs => {
    const nums = [...$divs].map(div => div.innerText)
    const zcta1Pop = parseInt(nums[1].replaceAll(',',''))
    const zcta2Pop = parseInt(nums[2].replaceAll(',',''))
    const totalResidents2 = zcta1Pop + zcta2Pop
    return cy.wrap(totalResidents2)
  })
  .as('totalResidents2')

cy.get('@totalResidents1')then(totalResidents1 => {
  cy.get('@totalResidents2').then(totalResidents2 => {
    expect(totalResidents1).to.eq(totalResidents2)
  })
})
```